# Dynamically populate external tables location

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use oracle external tables to load flat files into a database but I'm having a bit of an issue with the location clause. The files we receive are appended with several pieces of information including the date so I was hoping to use wildcards in the location clause but it doesn't look like I'm able to.

I think I'm right in assuming I'm unable to use wildcards, does anyone have a suggestion on how I can accomplish this without writing large amounts of code per external table?

Current thoughts:

The only way I can think of doing it at the moment is to have a shell watcher script and parameter table. User can specify: input directory, file mask, external table etc. Then when a file is found in the directory, the shell script generates a list of files found with the file mask. For each file found issue a alter table command to change the location on the given external table to that file and launch the rest of the pl/sql associated with that file. This can be repeated for each file found with the file mask. I guess the benefit to this is I could also add the date to the end of the log and bad files after each run.

Comment: Why a large amount of code - so you can identify a specific file name (with utl_file, say) and then alter the external table's location to point to that? You might be able to do something with a preprocessor; will more than on session/process access the external table simultaneously?

Comment: I guess it was discussed in AskTom here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:37593123416931

Comment: The external table is the first part of the loading process, after that a pl/sql package is launched to enrich/load the data. I was going to schedule these using a oracle job. So more than one job could be running at the same time but they shouldn't be accessing the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution I went with in the end which appears to be the only way.

I have a file watcher than looks for files in a given input dir with a certain file mask. The lookup table also includes the name of the external table. I then simply issue an alter table on the external table with the list of new file names.

For me this wasn't much of an issue as I'm already using shell for most of the file watching and file manipulation. Hopefully this saves someone searching for ages for a solution.